# Faster list lookup

Tags: python, performance

I have a json file that looks something similar to this:

```
{
  "urls": [
    "phantomweb.app",
    "aurory.app",
    "solvision.io",
    "staratlas.art",
    "starsatlas.com",
    "sollet.cc",
    "raydlum.io",
    "aurorynft.com",
    "solletweb.io",
    "fancyfrenchienft.art",
    "solanawebwallet.online"
  ]
}
```

I need to use this JSON file as a blocklist to lookup a domain, and I need to do it quickly. Currently I'm doing it like so:

```
def fast_list_lookup(lst, search):
    from bisect import bisect_left

    return (search <= lst[-1]) and (lst[bisect_left(lst, search)] == search)


def check_domain_blocklist(url, blocklist_path="/tmp/blocklist.json"):
    import urlparse

    with io.open(blocklist_path) as fh:
        data = json.load(fh)["urls"]
        data.sort()
        parsed_domain = urlparse.urlparse(url).netloc
        return fast_list_lookup(data, parsed_domain)
```

Don't get me wrong this is fairly quick:

```
for _ in {1..5}; do time python test.py; done

real    0m3.228s
user    0m0.511s
sys     0m0.296s

real    0m3.778s
user    0m0.504s
sys     0m0.530s

real    0m4.048s
user    0m0.594s
sys     0m0.537s

real    0m4.131s
user    0m0.761s
sys     0m0.386s

real    0m4.204s
user    0m0.700s
sys     0m0.488s
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to optimize the file loading, or list sorting so that I can trim the time down by a second or two?

Comment: Couldn't you use a different structure (for example, a set) for your lookups?

Comment: It adds time to turn the JSON list into a set and then go through it then it does to just sort the list and go from there. Also the urls will always be coming from a JSON file

Comment: Isn't sorting a list O(N log N) and converting from a list to a set O(N)? I would expect the list to set conversion to be faster than sorting on large lists.

Comment: If you are only doing this once, then its not worth optimizing.  If you are doing it repeatedly, you only have to convert the list once and then reap the benefits with each lookup.

Comment: "It adds time" is conjecture. **Test and find out**. Using a `set` is the answer here unless you have an extremely compelling (e.g. quantified) reason it won't work. I'd argue that what you really want is to mash this down into a more minimal representation of a regular expression, but that's a lot more work than just using `set`.

Comment: This makes no sense. Why sort and bisect instead of simply a linear search?

Comment: How large is the actual list, and what does `test.py` do? You're asking us to optimize something we can't see.

Comment: I'm a bit out of my depth, but I think you should [use a profiler](/questions/582336/how-do-i-profile-a-python-script) to figure out which part of the script is slowest. Then you can figure out what to focus on (i.e. file loading, sorting, or lookup, or some other part for that matter). For now, the question is too broad, but FWIW, there's an existing question: [Most Efficient Way to Find Whether a Large List Contains a Specific String](/q/872290/4518341) (TLDR use a `set`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this repeatedly, then I would build a closure (or a class) that when initialized cast the list to a set. Otherwise, if you were just going to do this once, performance is not likely to matter as initializing any search strategy is likely to take just as long as iteration of the list one time.

Here is how I might approach a closure:

```py
import json
import urlparse

def build_blocklist_checker(path="/tmp/blocklist.json"):
    with open(path, "r") as file_in:
        lookup = set(json.load(file_in)["urls"])
    return lambda url: urlparse.urlparse(url).netloc in lookup

blocklist_checker = build_blocklist_checker()
print(blocklist_checker("sollet.cc"))
```